# What should I check after I do PCA?

Tags: pca, factor-analysis, eigenvalues

I have X in which each row is a sample and each column is a predictor.

I de-mean X first and then construct the co-variance matrix

$A=X^{T}X$

after that I do PCA

$AP=PD$

while each column in P is an eigen vector and each element in D's diagonal is an eigen value --- in a sorted manner.

Now, here comes the question: what kind of sanity check should I do?

I think I should do the following:

1. compare the absolute values of sorted eigenvalues, is the largest one reasonably bigger than the second largest one?
2. variance of eigenvalues. However, I don't know what should I check for. What does it mean when the eigenvalues have a large/small variance?

anything else I should check ?

Comment: While I fully support the idea of running model diagnostics, PCA "always works" in the sense that given no extremely unusual numerical artefacts occur, the results are factually correct. The decomposition is valid. You might question how many PCs you should use but that is a different question relating to the use of the PCA results rather on the validity of the decomposition.

Comment: What are you trying to check? Are you trying to verify that the transformation you computed is in fact PCA, or are you trying to find out whether it is sufficient to keep only some of the principal components?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: There are a number of conceptual issues with the post. As mentioned in the comment above, PCA decomposes the matrix, and for a correlation matrix, this will always work. Second, the eigenvalues have no variance..the eigenvalues squared give a cumulative measure of variance explained. Please elaborate on exactly what it is you want to check. It seems your question is about how many factors to retain.